# What is the replacement of Plugin.DeviceInfo.Abstractions in .NET MAUI

Tags: maui

I am currently upgrading my Xamarin project to .NET 7 MAUI. Doing lot of research but could not find it.

I am getting below error.

> The type or namespace name 'Plugin' could not be found.

```
using Plugin.DeviceInfo.Abstractions;
```